# Resolution changed after an update and can't change back

Tags: drivers, nvidia, display, display-resolution

I updated (not upgraded) my laptop running 16.04, and I don't know what happened but after a reboot my screen resolution changed and I can't change it back.

Under the Settings->Displays I only have "1024x768 (4:3)" option, and it makes my screen all crooked because that's not the original aspect ratio or resolution.

I have a NVidia G-Fource 540M card, with the NVidia-367 driver.
I tried to change drivers but it didn't help.

I also have the `nomodeset` flag in grub, as I had a problem recently with lightdm and logging in.

Output of `sudo lspci | grep -i vga`

> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
>   01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 540M] (rev a1)

Output of `xrandr`

> xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
>   Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
>   default connected primary 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
>      1024x768      76.00*

I am so tired of having problems with my display recently... It's so annoying :\